# TCP Chat : Server sends to multiple client

Tags: c#, tcp, chat, tcpclient, tcplistener

So i'm working on a C# Chat using TCP protocol and i cant figure out how to make the server send data received by a client to all the clients connected to him . So i tried to put all client into an arraylist and with the use of a "foreach" sending them data received by the server [like in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795133/how-to-send-data-to-all-connected-socket-connection-using-tcpclient-from-another) but i failed .
For sending and receiving data i'm using Streams (StreamWriter / StreamReader).Each client is handled in a different thread by the server.

Question : How to send data to all the clients at the same time ?

Server :

```
static void LoopClients()
{
    while (running)
    {
        TcpClient newClient = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        arrClient.add(newClient)

        Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + ((IPEndPoint)newClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address);

        Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClient));
        t.Start(newClient);
    }
}

static void HandleClient(object obj)
{
    TcpClient client = (TcpClient)obj;

    StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
    StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

    Boolean ClientConnected = true;
    String Data = null;
    var LEP = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
    var LAD = LEP.Address;


    while (ClientConnected)
    {
        Data = Reader.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine(""+ LAD + " : " + Data);

        Writer.WriteLine(LAD+" : "+Data+"");
        Writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Thank You !

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I can see you get as far as trying to read a line from each socket; where have you tried t write? Note: thread-per-client is a *horrible* way to write a service unless it will only ever have a very small number of clients, and `StreamReader.ReadLine` (and similar) are not usually a good idea in a TCP server (although I guess *that* won't matter if it has a dedicated thread per client)

Comment: @MarcGravell For now the server only sends back what the client have sent and the chat is only suposed to work for 5 to 10 people .All of the "writing" is made in a client thread should i move it outside the thread in a method for exemple ?

Comment: @Haza but right now it *doesn't* send the data *anywhere*...

Comment: @MarcGravell It does send to the client the same data the client sent "Writer.WriteLine(LAD+" : "+Data+"");" Writer is the StreamWriter aiming for the current client

Comment: @Haza ah gotcha; so ... you'll need to keep a reference to all the other socket representations, and also write to them? noting that thread-safety is a thing, and you need to think about what happens when two people send a message at exactly the same time - are you ever trying to write to the same socket twice at a time?

Comment: @MarcGravell "you'll need to keep a reference to all the other socket representations, and also write to them? " if it helps me sending data to all the clients at the same time and so making a chat yes ! and i didnt tried to write to the same socket twice at a time why ?

Comment: @Haza because `Socket` isn't thread-safe for multiple concurrent reads or multiple concurrent writes; you *are* allowed to read and write concurrently, but only at most one read and one write at a time. Essentially you're going to be doing something like `foreach(var client in clientList) client.Send(message);` - and if that is happening from two threads at once (because two messages were received), you don't want to **write** to the same socket twice at the same time.

Comment: @MarcGravell So with what should i replace the socket if it cant handle multiple request at the same time ?

Comment: @Haza you just need to synchronize; sec..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you need to track all the clients somehow. This *could* be as simple as tracking all the `StreamWriter` in a synchronized collection, and ensure you remove from it when sessions terminate. For example:

```
StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
try {
    lock(allClients) { allClients.Add(Writer); }
    while (ClientConnected)
    {
        ...
    }
} finally {
    lock(allClients) { allClients.Remove(Writer); }
}
```

Now we need to do something when we want to send a message to everyone. Perhaps the *simplest* thing to to is a synchronized sweep:

```
lock(allClients) {
    foreach(var writer in allClients)
        try { writer.Send(message); } catch { /* log */ }
}
```

This synchronizes the entire collection - so as long as this is the *only* place that sends messages, then you know a: that you're never trying to send to the same socket twice at once, and b: that you're not going to break the iterator by having a socket add/remove.

Caveat: this is a very very crude and basic implementation of a multi-client server, and should really only be used as an *introduction* to the topic. "Real" multi-client servers should be *much* more paranoid that this.

Comment: Thank you i will try that solution , looks like i missed a lot of concept in C# network programming i should try more .  Thanks again !