# C# using Socket to send message to all client

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

My objective here to to send a message to the connected clients from my server. The code is working but the only problem is, it can only send message to the client who sent the command. What I need is to received the message by other client. I saw this code in youtube and make a few adjustment. Please find below.

**Server Code**

```
class Program
    {
        private static readonly Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        private static readonly List<Socket> clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
        private const int PORT = 100;
        private static readonly byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Server";
            SetupServer();
            Console.ReadLine(); // When we press enter close everything
            CloseAllSockets();
        }


        private static void SetupServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT));
            serverSocket.Listen(0);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
            Console.WriteLine("Server setup complete");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Close all connected client (we do not need to shutdown the server socket as its connections
        /// are already closed with the clients).
        /// </summary>
        private static void CloseAllSockets()
        {
            foreach (Socket socket in clientSockets)
            {
                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
            }

            serverSocket.Close();
        }

        private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket;

            try
            {
                socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException) // I can not seem to avoid this (on exit when properly closing sockets)
            {
                return;
            }

            clientSockets.Add(socket);
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", socket.RemoteEndPoint + " connected...");
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
        }

        private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int received;

            try
            {
                received = current.EndReceive(AR);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client forcefully disconnected");
                // Don't shutdown because the socket may be disposed and its disconnected anyway.
                current.Close();
                clientSockets.Remove(current);
                return;
            }

            byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(buffer, recBuf, received);
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);
            Console.WriteLine("Received Text: " + text);

            if (text.ToLower() == "meeting") // Client requested time
            {
                foreach (Socket socket in clientSockets)
                {
                    //current = socket;
                    string message = "meeting";
                    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                    socket.Send(data);
                    //socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, null, null);
                    Console.WriteLine("Meeting invite sent to " + socket.RemoteEndPoint);
                }

            }
            else if (text.ToLower() == "exit") // Client wants to exit gracefully
            {
                // Always Shutdown before closing
                Console.WriteLine(current.RemoteEndPoint + " disconnected");
                current.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                current.Close();
                clientSockets.Remove(current);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid request");
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Invalid request");
                current.Send(data);
                Console.WriteLine("Warning Sent");
            }


            current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
        }


    }
```

### **Client Code**

```
namespace TCP_Client {
    public partial class frmTCPClient : Form
    {
        private readonly Socket ClientSocket = new Socket
            (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        private const int PORT = 100;
        private byte[] buffer;
        private string message { get; set; }
        public string serverMessage { get; set; }

        public frmTCPClient()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmTCPClient_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConnectToServer();
            //UpdateControls();
        }

        private void UpdateControls()
        {
            lblMessage.Text = message;
            //txtFromServer.Text = serverMessage;
        }

        private void ConnectToServer()
        {
            int attempts = 0;

            while (!ClientSocket.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    attempts++;
                    //lblMessage.Text = "Connection attempt " + attempts;
                    // Change IPAddress.Loopback to a remote IP to connect to a remote host.
                    //ClientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, PORT);
                    ClientSocket.Connect("172.20.110.129", PORT);
                }
                catch (SocketException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + "Connection attempt " + attempts);
                }
            }

            message = "Connected";
        }

        private void RequestLoop()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                SendRequest("");
                ReceiveResponse();
            }
        }

        private void SendRequest(string text)
        {
            string request = text;
            SendString(request);

            if (request.ToLower() == "exit")
            {
                Exit();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a string to the server with ASCII encoding.
        /// </summary>
        private void SendString(string text)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
                ClientSocket.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendRequest(txtMessage.Text);
            ReceiveResponse();
            UpdateControls();
        }


        private void Exit()
        {
            SendString("exit"); // Tell the server we are exiting
            ClientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            ClientSocket.Close();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        public void ReceiveResponse()
        {
            var buffer = new byte[2048];
            try
            {
                if (buffer.ToString().Length == 2048) return;
                int received = ClientSocket.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
                if (received == 0) return;
                var data = new byte[received];
                Array.Copy(buffer, data, received);
                string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
                txtFromServer.Text += text + System.Environment.NewLine;
                //MessageBox.Show(text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
        }

        private void frmTCPClient_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Exit();

        }
    } }
```

Update

```
 foreach (object obj in clientSockets) 
 { 
    string message = "meeting"; 
    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message); 
    Socket socket = (Socket)obj; 
    socket.Send(data); 
    Console.WriteLine("Meeting invite sent to " + socket.RemoteEndPoint);
  }
```

---

Image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeOxS.png)

Comment: It's not related your current code but I think SignalR is what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send data to all connected socket connection using Tcpclient from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795133/how-to-send-data-to-all-connected-socket-connection-using-tcpclient-from-another)

Comment: just added below code but still not working. Thanks  ` foreach (object obj  in clientSockets)
                {
                    string message = "meeting";
                    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                    Socket socket = (Socket)obj;
                    socket.Send(data);
                    Console.WriteLine("Meeting invite sent to " + socket.RemoteEndPoint);
                }` @TheGeneral

Comment: @AlvinCollao this is how you do it, keep managed list of sockets, and when you want to broadcast send it to each of the sockets. if you are having further troubles please paste the error message

Comment: @TheGeneral there is no error found but only one client received the message. ---

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeOxS.png

Comment: You code looks OK.  Try looking at what's actually being sent with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html).  [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) isn't necessarily a bad suggestion, either.

Comment: Not your current problem but your server seems to have **one** buffer and yet you're setting it up to receive input from **multiple** clients. The whole design is broken.